# Postman, sharing a dynamic variable between tests

Tags: variables, time, collections, postman

I have a Postman collection of four tests. In the collection's pre-request scripts tab, I created a dynamic date (timeVariable). When I Run my test scripts from the collection level, the console log shows the timeVariable value for each test, but when I review the results, the timeVariable value is empty. In my pre-request scripts I do set the `pm.env.sets()` as:

```
pm.environment.set("timeVariable", resultTime);
```

but my tests remain blank for the timeVariable.

- Do I need to use QA instead of environment?
- Do I need to use timeVariable with no quotes?
- Do I need to use the set command in each test?

Any kind of suggestions? Thank you

I have tried most of everything but figure I need to reset the timeVariable every time so the each test sees the value. I assumed since the value came from the collection level, but the test results page shows the timeVariable as time:{{timevariable}} as Time:""